# SQL Subquery issue 3

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a issue with my SQL code.

When I run this code I'm getting such error mesage:

**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

**

I don't know how to correct this code to run it?

Can somebothy look at it and help me with it?

Thank you for your help,

```
SELECT dbo.FRA$.[GUID], dbo.FRA$.[Last Name], 

dbo.FRA$.[First Name], dbo.FRA$.[HR Manager Last Name], 

dbo.FRA$.[HR Manager First Name], (SELECT dbo.FRA$.[Business Email Address] FROM dbo.FRA$ t WHERE t.[HR Manager ID] = t.[Emplid]) AS [HR Manager E-Mail],

dbo.LOC.Descr AS [COMPANY NAME], dbo.FRA$.[Location Code],

dbo.LOC.[ADDRESS], dbo.LOC.Postal, dbo.LOC.City, dbo.FRA$.[National ID], dbo.FRA$.[Current Employee Class Desc] AS [Current Empl Class],

dbo.FRA$.[Contract type description] AS [CONTRACT TYPE], dbo.FRA$.[Business Title],

CASE dbo.FRA$.[Current Employee Class Desc]
WHEN 'Operator' THEN 10
WHEN 'Clerical worker' THEN 22
WHEN 'Technician' THEN 32
WHEN 'Supervisor' THEN 33
WHEN 'Manager&Engineer' THEN 54
END AS [Salary brutto],

FORMAT(dbo.FRA$.[Birthdate],'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [Birth Date], FORMAT(dbo.FRA$.[Last Start Date],'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [Hire Date]

FROM dbo.FRA$  

INNER JOIN dbo.LOC 

ON dbo.FRA$.[Location Code] = dbo.LOC.[Location]

WHERE [HR Status] IN ('International Assignment','Active','Leave of Absence');
```

Comment: And this query is supposed to run on MySQL and MS SQL Server and Sqlite???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
SELECT dbo.FRA$.[Business Email Address] FROM dbo.FRA$ t WHERE t.[HR Manager ID] = t.[Emplid]
```

with

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.[Business Email Address] FROM dbo.FRA$ t WHERE [HR Manager ID] = t.[Emplid]
```

it will take only one row from rows returned by your subquery

Comment: Hi Dimitry, Thank you for your help. I have tried and I got a result that the code shows me the employee email and not the HR Manager Email Address?

Comment: hello Mirek. I edited my answer. You ought to bind `t.[Emplid]` from a subquery table to `[HR Manager ID]` from the maintable. Just remove `t.` or better make an alias for the main table.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have corrected to this SELECT TOP 1 dbo.FRA$.[Business Email Address] FROM dbo.FRA$ t WHERE dbo.FRA$.[HR Manager ID] = t.[Emplid]) AS [HR Manager E-Mail] but still getting email from the employee not the HR Manager?

Comment: or even issue can be in `SELECT dbo.FRA$.[Business Email Address]`. Probably you need to use alias `t` for this `SELECT t.[Business Email Address]`

Comment: Mirek, I made a few edits and finally try `(SELECT TOP 1 t.[Business Email Address] FROM dbo.FRA$ t WHERE [HR Manager ID] = t.[Emplid])`

Comment: Dmitry, thank you your last comment and regarding the aliases works perfect :) Thank you!